# Maintain div scroll position on postback with html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, postback, maintainscrollpositionon

Is there a way to maintain the div scroll position on a postback, without using asp? So far I've only found solutions using asp.

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.x2line.com/al/articles/156.aspx

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script language="javascript">
    // function saves scroll position
    function fScroll(val)
    {
        var hidScroll = document.getElementById('hidScroll');
        hidScroll.value = val.scrollTop;
    }

    // function moves scroll position to saved value
    function fScrollMove(what)
    {
        var hidScroll = document.getElementById('hidScroll');
        document.getElementById(what).scrollTop = hidScroll.value;
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="fScrollMove('div_scroll');" onunload="document.forms(0).submit()";>

<form>

<input type="text" id="hidScroll" name="a"><br>
<div id="div_scroll" onscroll="fScroll(this);" style="overflow:auto;height:100px;width:100px;">

   .. VERY LONG TEXT GOES HERE

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried setting up his example filling it with lipsum, and it dosn't seem to work. The comments on the source page don't sound too promising either. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this javascript code works for you

```
        function loadScroll ()
        {
            var m = /[&?]qs\=(\d+)/.exec (document.location);
            if (m != null)
                myDiv.scrollTop = parseInt (m[1]);
        }

        function saveScroll ()
        {
            var form = document.getElementById ("myForm");
            var sep = (form.action.indexOf ("?") == -1) ? "?" : "&";
            form.action += sep + "qs=" + myDiv.scrollTop;
        }
```

Now, you can watch for the "submit" event to save the position in the "action" attribute:

```
        document.getElementById ("myForm").addEventListener ("submit", saveScroll, false);
```

And in your BODY tag...

```
<body onload="loadScroll ();">
    ....
</body>
```

I can't test the code right now, but I think you get the idea.